# After 2 hours the TCP socket connection get sleep and after 36 min goes on from the same point it stopped (with no errors)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP client running on raspbian and a TCP server on Ubuntu. I have made this with c++ sockets. I am sending 3MB every second (are images) and it works perfectly until 2 hours more or less (2h26m, 2h16m, 2h18m...) and it has sent 7100 files aprox (7147, 7071, 7471... it is not a second exactly), after this time the connection get stop, but there's no errors, just is like it stays asleep. After 36 minutes (always 36 minutes) it goes on again from the same instruction it was stop, and the codes keep on with no problem.

I did it: I open one socket and I keep opened. The send and receive functions are inside a infinite while (in both client and server), like this:

1. Client:

   ```
       While(1)                       
       {                              
            send();
            cout << Hi 1 << endl;           
            recv();
            send();
            recv();
            cout << Hi 2 << endl;
        }
   ```
2. Server:

   ```
   While(1)                       
   {                              
        recv();
        cout << Hi 1 << endl;                      
        send();
        recv();
        cout << Hi 2 << endl;
        send();
    }
   ```

When it stops, it does in the second or the third function (I know because the first cout prints on screen). When this happens I check out the CPU process (there is no process, it is 5-10% ) and the memory it is not filled up at all, so the computers are not blocked I can move the mouse, open programs, write with the keyboard...

It's made in an LAN, with a router (I have tried with another one with the same results)... I have changed the tcp_keepalive_time (7200, 86400 and 300), but same results...
The program doesn't crash...
And after 36 minutes goes on from the same instruction, with no data lost, with no errors...

I would like to keep the connection and send images constantly every second for a long long time (days), but I have no idea why what I just explained (it takes a break for a while) is happening.

This is the server code (the while is inside a thread):

```
while(1)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    cout << "Esperant image..." << contador << endl;
    int bytes_recieved , si = 1;
    int long rebut;  
    char send_data[35]="", FI[5]="1";
    char INFO[50], NOM1[8]="" ,NOM[12]="", DISP[7]="", W[5]="", H[5]="", B[2]="", R[5]="", X0[5]="", Y0[5]="", T[9]="";



    // ... 2.. Rebre        
    if(recv(*csock1, INFO, sizeof(INFO), 0)==-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    for(int k =0; k < sizeof(INFO);k++)
    {
        if(k>=0 && k <= 6) DISP[k]=INFO[k];
        DISP[7]='\0';
        if(k>=8 && k <= 13) NOM1[k-8]=INFO[k];
        NOM1[6]='\0';
        if(k>=15 && k <= 18) W[k-15]=INFO[k];
        W[4]='\0';
        if(k>=20 && k <= 23) H[k-20]=INFO[k];
        H[4]='\0';
        if(k==25) B[0]=INFO[k];
        B[2]='\0'; //
        if(k>=27 && k <= 30) R[k-27]=INFO[k];
        R[4]='\0';
        if(k>=32 && k <= 35) X0[k-32]=INFO[k];
        X0[4]='\0';
        if(k>=37 && k <= 40) Y0[k-37]=INFO[k];
        Y0[4]='\0';
        if(k>=42 && k <= 48) T[k-42]=INFO[k];
        T[7]='\0';
    }
    strcat(NOM, DISP);
    strcat(NOM, NOM1);
    if(format_image ==1) strcat(NOM, ".raw");
    if(format_image ==2) strcat(NOM, ".jpg");
    //cout << INFO << endl;
    //cout << "Nom: " << NOM << endl;
    ample = atoi(W);
    alt = atoi(H);
    BYTES = atoi(B);
    TAM = ample*alt*BYTES;
    printf("Image: %s - Tamany: (%ix%i) x %iBytes = %i Bytes\n",NOM, ample,alt,BYTES,TAM);
    if(strcmp(DISP, "RASP01_")==0)
    {
        XP=0;
        YP=0;
    }
    if(strcmp(DISP, "RASP00_")==0)
    {
        XP=450;
        YP=0;
    }
    if(strcmp(DISP, "RASP02_")==0)
    {
        XP=0;
        YP=400;
    }               
    window_name = DISP;
    r = atoi(R);
    x0 = atoi(X0);
    y0 = atoi(Y0);
    tam = atoi(T);
    printf("Circul r=%i, x0=%i, y0=%i, %i Bytes\n",r,x0,y0,tam);

    if(reduccio==true) tam_reb = tam;
    else tam_reb = TAM;
    image_reb = (char*) malloc (tam_reb);
    data = (char*) malloc (TAM);

    // ... 3 .. Enviar Confirmacio
    if(send(*csock1,"Conectat a CERVELL",46,0)==-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    cout << "3" << endl;

    //#... 4 .. Rebre l'IMAGE
        REP = 0;
        do{
            rebut = recv(*csock1,&image_reb[REP],tam_reb-REP,0);
            if (rebut<0) goto FINISH;  //rebut=0
            REP = REP + (int)rebut;
            cout << "."; 
        }while(rebut>0 && REP<=tam_reb);
        cout << "Image Rebuda:  " << REP << endl;
        //printf("Temps de recepcio: %fs\n", ((double)clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    // ... 5 .. Enviar Confirmacio
    if(send(*csock1,"1",5,0)==-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

    // Reconstruir image (Generar Circul de Visio)  
    if(reduccio==true) //reduccio==true)
    {
        int xs,cx,k2=0,N, Xc, XN, N1,j,i, r2=pow(r,2);
        N = y0-r;
        if(N<0) N=0;
        i = N*ample;
        for( j=0; j<alt; j++ )
        {
           xs=(int)floor(x0-abs(sqrt(r2-pow(r-j,2))));
           cx=(int)floor(abs(sqrt(r2 - pow(r-j,2))));
           N=j*ample;
           N1=N+ample;
           XN=N+xs;
           Xc=XN+2*cx;

           //for(i=i; i<XN; i++) data[i] = 255;
           memset ( &data[i], 255, XN-i );
           i = XN -1;
           memcpy(&data[i],&image_reb[k2],Xc-XN);
           i=i+Xc-XN;
           k2=k2+Xc-XN;
           //for(i=Xc; i<N1; i++)   data[i] = 255;
           memset ( &data[i], 255, N1-i );
           i = N1 - 1;
        }
        printf("\nTamany de mensage reconstruit:  %i\n",i);
    } 

        // Convertir a MATRIU i GUARDAR
        if (1)  //REP == tam_reb
        {
            //string format;
            //if (BYTES == 4) format =  'CV_8UC4';; //Scalar(128,128,128));   CV_8UC3   CV_32F  Size(1920, 1080), CV_8UC3
            //if (BYTES == 1) format =  'CV_8UC1';
            //if(reduccio==true)
            //  Mat M(Size(ample,alt), CV_8UC1,data);
            //if(reduccio==false)
            Mat M(Size(ample,alt), CV_8UC1,data);  //image_reb
            char ruta[100] = "/home/jk/Documents/02_Imagens/";
            strcat(ruta, NOM);
            //Guardar en RAW
            if(format_image ==1)
            {
                FILE *f = fopen(ruta,"w");
                if (f == 0) {
                    printf("************************No he pogut obrir %s\n", NOM);
                } else {
                    fwrite(data,1,TAM,f);
                    fclose(f);
                }
            }
            //Guardar en JPG
            if(format_image ==2)
            {
                if(imwrite(ruta, M , compression_params )<1)
                    cout << "Erro al guardar" << endl;
            }
            // Mostrar IMAGE
            namedWindow(window_name,0 );    // WINDOW_OPENGL //WINDOW_NORMAL //CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO  //CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE    
                //cvNamedWindow(window_name2, CV_WINDOW_OPENGL);
            //resizeWindow(window_name,680,480);
            moveWindow(window_name, XP, YP);
            //setOpenGlContext(window_name);
            //updateWindow(window_name);
            imshow( window_name, M );
            cvWaitKey(15);          

        } else printf("\n Tamany de l'Image no concorda\n");
    contador++;
    free(image_reb);
        free(data);
    printf("Tiempo transcurrido: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

}

Comment: Does it "stop" in the server, the client, or both? Whats happening on the network when the "stop" happens? What happens on the server and client computers? Are the server and client on the same computer? The same network segment? Different segments? Have you thought of adding another debug output *between* the two calls, to narrow it down even further?

Comment: What happens if you run both processes on the same machine? What about memory? Do you have any system time skews? Where exactly does it hang? Are there perhaps any overflows or underflows in the calculation of the sleep duration or timeout between different loop runs?

Comment: I have just started another probe by adding some code in order to find out which call stop in. So I need waiting about 2 hours. 

The Client is a Raspberry Pi and the server is in a laptop ubuntu. The memories are no busy, besides when it "stops" has been sent more than 30GB (if it was the memory, I supose it would have stoped quite before). The two devices are connected directly to the router. I haven't tried run the both on the same machine. The sleep instruction is in the client, so after the call functions.

Comment: The client computer is not very powerful (compared to the server anyway), it may be that the client simply doesn't manage to deal with that much data every second, so it falls behind ever so slightly, and after your two hours the receiving buffers on the client fills up, which means that the TCP window is zero, which means that the server can't send and blocks. It then takes 36 minutes for either the client to catch up, or for some timeout clearing the buffers and allowing data to be sent again.

Comment: I cannot imagine that there is any buffer being able to take 36min of data (which is 6.4GB).

Comment: When the buffers are full, the TCP window is zero, and the other end can't send anything during that time, which is why the server stops sending (if that happens?) So nothing is being sent at all during thse 36 minutes.

Comment: In addition to running both client and server on the same machine, you might try connecting the Raspberry Pi directly to the laptop (with just an ethernet cable).  If the symptoms go during that test, that would suggest that the problem is in the router.

Comment: Please post the send() and recv() functions.

Comment: I just edit my ask to add some code.
Ok, I will try connecting directly to the router and looking for a possible existing register (or instruction) which reset the buffers.

Comment: I have tried to connect directly without the router and I got the same result.

Comment: Use a debugger on both the client and the server to see where exactly each one stops (or loops).